# Unique array not working in a foreach loop

Tags: php

I am trying to stop an array of items from duplicating everytime the loop goes through. I would think unique array would solve my problem but it doesnt seem to be working. Is there an alternative or am I doing something wrong?

This is the array that i am parsing. For example bag shows up several times. I am trying get it to show up once.

```
Array
(
    [0] => bag
    [1] => wallet
    [2] => accessori
    [3] => sunglass
    [4] => clutch
    [5] => tote
)
Array
(
    [0] => handbag
    [1] => faux
    [2] => leather
    [3] => bag
    [4] => clutch
    [5] => hobo
    [6] => purs
    [7] => wallet
    [8] => tote
    [9] => messeng
)
Array
(
    [0] => bag
    [1] => book
)
```

This is my code.

```
foreach($json as $keywords){

    foreach($keywords as $keyword){

        print_r(array_unique($keyword['keywords']));

    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you update your question with json??

Comment: Are you trying to get unique records from all these 3 arrays? Please clarify this first.

Comment: 1. `array_unique()` does not work recursively, you will have to implement a wrapper for that and 2. I cannot spot any key named `'keywords'` in your arrays...

Comment: IF you can post your whole array then i can try by my side.

Comment: What's your expected output? E.g. where should "bag" be included in the result array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've wrote array_unique() function for multidimensial array
First, i've merged all the arrays, applied array_unique() and after that recomposed the result

```
<?php
$input  = array( array('bag',   'wallet' ),
                    array('wallet', 'purs'  ),
                    array('book',   'purs'  )       
                  );
print_r (arrayUniqueMultidimensial($input));

function arrayUniqueMultidimensial($input) {                
    $merged = array();
    foreach ($input as $subArray) {
        $merged = array_merge($merged, $subArray);
    }

    $filteredArray  = array_unique($merged, SORT_STRING);
    $segment        = array(0); // segmentation
    foreach($input as $subArray) {
        $segment[] = $segment[count($segment)-1] + count($subArray);
    }

    $recomposed = array();
    for($i=1 ; $i<count($segment) ; $i++) {
        $startIndex = $segment[$i-1];
        $endIndex    = $segment[$i] ;
        $temp        = array();
        for ($j=$startIndex ; $j<$endIndex ; $j++) {
            if (array_key_exists($j, $filteredArray)) {
                $temp[] = $filteredArray[$j];
            }
        }
        $recomposed[] = $temp;
    }
    return ($recomposed);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply merge all arrays first, then do the `array_unique`

```
    $a = array(
        'bag',
        'wallet',
        'accessori',
        'sunglass',
        'clutch',
        'tote'
    );
    $b = array(
        'handbag',
        'faux',
        'leather',
        'bag',
        'clutch',
        'hobo',
        'purs',
        'wallet',
        'tote',
        'messeng',
    );
    $c = array(
        'bag',
        'book',
    );
    $d = array_merge($a, $b, $c);
    var_dump($d);
    $u = array_unique($d);
    var_dump($u);
```

compare the variables $d an $u.